# Removing border around a Win32::GUI control

Tags: perl, listview, border, win32gui, perlapp

whenever I use PerlApp to generate a binary of my projects,
controls like the textbox and the listview have an ugly grey border around themselves.
([example picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJK8b.png))

I used the following code to create the listview:

```
my $listview = $main->AddListView(
    -size => [250,250],
    -name => 'listview',
    -pos => [50,50],
    -gridlines => 1,
    -sunken => 0,
    -border => 0,
    -borderstyle => 0,
);
```

Is there a solution to this problem?
Thank you,

Max.